# Profiling of Ruby Minitest tests

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, profiling, minitest

I have a lot of slow-running Minitest tests for Rails app (3-4 minutes on one test). I want to profile them to learn how to fix them.

I tried to use standard Ruby profiler and ruby-prof - neither worked. Standard Ruby profiler profiles... something, but it prints its results BEFORE running tests, and I get no information on them. Ruby-prof simply hangs my tests if I include RubyProf.start in the test.

The Internet is full of advices on profiling Rails apps. Hovever, I did not find any guide for profiling *tests* for Rails apps. Please, help me choose proper strategy for test profiling!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I was able to add the profile to my unit tests successfully by including `require 'profile'` at the top of my test file. It does hang at the beginning (maybe for 30 seconds) when it's setting up, but after the tests ran I got a detailed output on how much time was spent in different functions.

I ran the tests from the command line with `ruby -rprofile -I"lib:test" <test filepath>`.